# Trigger VBA Word macro based on Cell change Value

Tags: .net, vba, ms-word

Hi I need to trigger a macro in vba based on its value being changed by .Net application. For eg I have the following template
[Template populated by .Net application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaF5s.png)

I have the following code that needs to do substring on Cell(3,1) when it's value gets populated.

```
Sub Format()
Dim Str1 As String
Dim Str2 As String

tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Str1 = tbl.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text
Str2 = Split(Str1, " ")(0)
tbl.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = Str2

End Sub
```

The issue is this needs to be triggered when value in Cell(1,3) changes from <> to "This is Heading Three"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event that's triggered when the users edits in Word, unless you set up Windows API Keyboard hooks to monitor everything the user is doing.

When the user enters/leaves a table cell the WindowSelectionChange event of the Word.Application object is triggered. You could monitor that, check whether it's triggered by entering the cell in question and, if that's the case set a Boolean. When the event shows it's left the cell, reset the Boolean and check the current cell content.

You just have to be aware that monitoring this event can affect speed/efficiency of the Word application.